# Google+ share - cannot target to an iframe - get error: "This content cannot be displayed in a frame"

Tags: share, google-plus

I'm wondering if anyone else has had this problem.

I want to target the google+ share url to an iframe instead having to open up a new window.

the following is the test code that I'm using:

```
<?php
$url = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Feu.arithon.com%2Frss%2Fjobdetails.php%3Fclient_user_id%3Darithon_1348%26jobs_id%3D10000";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <iframe src = "<?php echo $url ?>" frameborder=no width=600 height=300></iframe>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openShareWindow()
        {   
            url =  "<?php echo $url ?>";
            window.open(url, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=400,width=600');
            return false;       
        }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="openShareWindow();">
        <img src="http://eu.arithon.com/new_arithonASP/new_images/arithon_post.jpg" alt="Share on Google+"/>
    </a>

</body>
</html>
```

In Internet Explorer, the iframe displays the error "This content cannot be displayed in a frame..." etc

In firefox, there is no error and the iframe is empty!

Is there any way that I can target the url to an iframe in IE without getting this error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The share URL is designed to open a new window and is not intended to open within an iframe, so using it like this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `<iframe>`, your results in IE can depend on what the source is that you're pulling in. In other words, some sources will work, some sources will create this problem. If you are getting the error message in IE, **"This content cannot be displayed in a frame. To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame,"** try the follwing:

Add `security="restricted"` to your  tag:

> <iframe src="YOUR_URL" security="restricted">

I had exactly this same issue when trying to pull in a Blogspot / Blogger blog. After adding the `security="restricted"` attribute, the problem went away.

Here's the documentation from Microsoft: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/01/18/using-frames-more-securely.aspx